# Using my iPhone, as a Wifi iPhone without a SIM card

Tags: iphone, sim, wifi-calling

I have recently given up my network phone service (removed my SIM card) and adopted a wifi based app that allows me to pay for my minutes as I go. Has anyone started this path to converting your iPhone to only a Wifi iPhone? if so... what are some of the complications encountered from not having a SIM card in the iPhone?

Comment: Without a SIM, how do you activate your phone?

Comment: @Allan, though I have never done the WiFi only phone thing an iPhone will activate as long as it has *some kind* of network connection. WiFi will do and I think it will even activate via iTunes and a USB cable.

Comment: @SteveChambers - You're correct - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201407#:~:text=If%20you%20still%20can%27t%20activate%2C%20here%27s%20how%20to,detects%20and%20activates%20your%20iPhone%3A%20More%20items%20  I've never done an activation without a SIM, but according to this, it should work.  However, under the 4th point, it says if it doesn't work, "contact your carrier" so you can probably activate without a SIM, but you need a *plan.*  I guess my question to the OP should have been "Without a valid service plan, how do you activate your phone?"